# How to remove weird right margin of overflow-y: scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

So I've been trying to add a vertical scroll into my modal. It was a half-success.

The CSS and all are working fine but I'm having this weird margin-right that seems like can't be removed.

I tried to play around with the inspect element and nothing is working.

By the way, when I removed the overflow-y: scroll the layout is okay (ofc, can't be scrolled)

So in my conclusion, the CSS overflow-y: scroll is the one that creates that weird margin-right.

Can someone help me or explain this time and How to remove it?

See the images attached for details.

PS. I think no need to post the code here since it's just CSS

[See the Weird Margin Right here]
[image]

[Inspect Elements]
[image]

Comment: Can you also provide the whole html code with css?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: here is the new question with CSS and HTML @Kameron 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70417294/8273998

Comment: @seantsang94121 you can check this new question instead. Thank you so much!

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70417294/8273998

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove weird right margin of overflow-y: auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417294/how-to-remove-weird-right-margin-of-overflow-y-auto)

Comment: Not really, I solved the issue myself. But thank you.